# How can I render an image inside canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I'm trying to render an image inside a canvas so then I can process it, the thing is that sometimes the image renders and sometimes it doesn't, am I missing something or is this something related to asyncronism? Thank you in advance.

This is the JavaScript I'm using.

```
let image, canvas, context;

const init = () => {
    image = document.getElementById('original');
    canvas = document.getElementById('result');

    // Set canvas properties
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    // Create canvas context
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    image.addEventListener('load', threshold);
}

const threshold = () => {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    const frame = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    for (let i = 0; i < frame.data.length; i++) {
        // pixels logic
    }

    context.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

And here's my HTML.

```
<main>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="../img/landscape.jpeg" id="original">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <canvas id="result"></canvas>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="../javascript/threshold.js"></script>
```

Comment: Haven't encountered such an issue. I listen for the "load" event of the window object - the images'll be there (loaded or failed) if you wait till then unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: You're setting the canvas dimensions in the init function, which runs when the domContentLoaded event fires. However that's not confirmation that the image has completed loading, only that the browser is ready to perform its first paint. Try setting the canvas dimensions at the start of the threshold function. Also, I suggest you use image.naturalWidth and image.naturalHeight rather than width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing it this way

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    time = document.getElementById('time');
    image = document.getElementById('input');
    canvas = document.getElementById('output');

    // Create canvas context
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    image.onload = threshold();
});
```

I added the event listener to `window` instead of `document`, and to wait until image loads I have used this `image.onload = threshold();` instead of `image.addEventListener('load', threshold);`.

Actually I don't know why it was behaving that way but now it is fixed.